# How to catch base exception class in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, exception

I'd like to catch any RoR exceptions in REST API application with 'rescue_from'.

```
rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
  message = Rails.env.production? ? 'API server error' : exception.message
  render json: {status: "Error", message: message}, status: :internal_server_error
end
```

but it catches too much irrelevant exceptions. Can I catch RoR exceptions only? Is it a good practice at all? If not, what else you can recommend?

Comment: What do you mean by “RoR exceptions only.” Is `ZeroDivision`, thrown from the controller/model that mistakenly tried to calculate the average for zero number of items, “the RoR one”?

Comment: @mudasobwa: for example, routing errors, missing parameters, record not found etc.

Comment: How on the Earth `RecordNotFound` is Rails-specific? There could be an application that uses the database (and `ActiveRecord`) completely aside from Rails. For routing errors see [`ActionControllerError`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/exceptions.rb). BTW, what do you plan to do with other exceptions thrown? Just let your application die?

Comment: @mudasobwa: give your better solution. This is a reason a question was asked.

Comment: Currently I catch following errors:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, ActionController::ParameterMissing, ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (respond with :bad_request - looks like API client's error)
Anything else catched with StandardError (respond with :internal_server_error)

This prevents application to die early.

Comment: hmmm you want to provide better errors for your API users , right ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always go out and get an exhaustive list of all the Rails exceptions, but honestly your first step should be to decide what situations you want to rescue from and which you want to allow to behave catastrophically. Not all exceptions should be caught.

If you're dead set on catching all Rails exceptions you should go look at the api documentation for the version of rails you're on and find the base classes for the exceptions you care about. For example, if you're hoping to just catch all ActiveRecord ones, you can rescue from the base [ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord/ActiveRecordError) class.

Again, I'd stress that you should be approaching this from the other direction--not rescuing everything and then trying to thin it out, but by rescuing from the bare minimum and adding as needed.